# EventHandler managment in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

Hi I am right now in an project using VB.NET and needs to translate this C# code into VB.NET

```
oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;

newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
```

For me it seems like the an event hooking up on an another event?
But I have tried everything to translate this into VB.NET code?
I have found out that EventHandler management in VB.NET is far from as good it is in C# as many other things.

So how can I do this in VB.NET?

Edit: here is the code I want to transalate all code is easy to translate but the code in the method OnCommandChanged.

```
public class CommandReference : Freezable, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(CommandReference),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandChanged)));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Command != null)
            return Command.CanExecute(parameter);
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Command.Execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommandReference commandReference = d as CommandReference;
        ICommand oldCommand = e.OldValue as ICommand;
        ICommand newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand;

        if (oldCommand != null)
        {
            oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
        }
        if (newCommand != null)
        {
            newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"as far from as good"? It's just as good, the semantics are just different :)

Try

```
RemoveHandler okButton.Click, addressof OkButton_ClickHandler

AddHandler okButton.Click, addressof OkButton_ClickHandler
```

**Update**

Hi, I missed the intent of your question, apologies.

I'm puzzled by your approach, when you put += and -= between the two event, you're not hooking and unhooking the events, you're only adding and removing the *the handlers that exist at that moment*. i.e. you're not hooking event a to event b, you're hooking the handlers that b currently has assigned to a. So if (for example) after the assignment all the handlers are removed from b *they will still be assigned to a*.

I'm probably missing something obvious sorry, also I don't have time right now to dig into how Dependency properties are implemented in WPF, which is where I'd look next.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Have you tested that code and compiled it? I have tested just that and got the following compiler error:
Error 1 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)

It seems like it wont allow me to use addressof on an event.

Comment: It wasn't obvious what you're arguements were, so I updated the answer to make it clearer. The first argurment is the event, the second is the address of the method to be called in response to the event.

Comment: ok, but as you see that solution wont solve my problem, my scenario is that I have two objects in matter of fact I have two instances of ICommand which both has an CanExecuteChanged event on them, this method will link the two events together. So I can't solve it as you presented it now :(. Is this an limitation in Vb.Net event handling?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) and [RemoveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac.aspx), which are built-in functions. Not as clear-cut as C#, but useful.

Also covered in the [VB Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem when I was implementing an special `INotifyCollectionChanged` when I needed to know if the instance had event handlers attached.

After a little bit of searching, I took a page out of the `ObservableCollecion(Of T)` in order to do it.

The code you're trying to convert to VB is:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; 

private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    CommandReference commandReference = d as CommandReference; 
    ICommand oldCommand = e.OldValue as ICommand; 
    ICommand newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand; 

    if (oldCommand != null) 
    { 
        oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= commandReference.CanExecuteChanged; 
    } 
    if (newCommand != null) 
    { 
        newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += commandReference.CanExecuteChanged; 
    } 
}
```

you need a little bit more code, but it's something like this:

```
Private __CanExecuteCommand as EventHandler

Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler 
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        Dim handler2 As EventHandler
        Dim canExecuteCommand = __CanExecuteCommand
        Do
            handler2 = canExecuteCommand
            Dim handler3 = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(handler2, value), EventHandler)
            canExecuteCommand = Interlocked.CompareExchange((__CanExecuteCommand), handler3, handler2)
        Loop While (Not canExecuteCommand Is handler2)
        __CanExecuteCommand = canExecuteCommand
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        Dim handler2 As EventHandler
        Dim canExecuteCommand = __CanExecuteCommand
        Do
            handler2 = canExecuteCommand
            Dim handler3 = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Remove(handler2, value), EventHandler)
            canExecuteCommand = Interlocked.CompareExchange((__CanExecuteCommand), handler3, handler2)
        Loop While (Not canExecuteCommand Is handler2)
        __CanExecuteCommand = CanExecuteCommand
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (__CanExecuteCommand IsNot Nothing) Then
            __CanExecuteCommand.Invoke(sender, e)
        End If
    End RaiseEvent
End Event

Private Shared Sub OnCommandChanged(d as DependencyObject, e as DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) 

    Dim commandReference = CType(d, CommandReference) 
    Dim oldCommand = CType(e.OldValue, ICommand) 
    Dim newCommand = CType(e.NewValue, ICommand)

    If (oldCommand IsNot Nothing) Then
        RemoveHandler oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged, commandReference.__CanExecuteChanged; 
    End If
    If (newCommand IsNot Nothing)  Then
        AddHandler newCommand.CanExecuteChanged, commandReference.__CanExecuteChanged; 
    End If

End Sub
```

So now you can not only check if the event has handlers as also move them around.